# Get current clock speed with ManagementObjectSearcher

Tags: vb.net, cpu, frequency

I'd like to get the current clock speed. All search results suggest WMI. Problem is, it doesn't work. For example, I overclocked my CPU to test it (increased it by 200 MHz). CPU-Z reported it correctly, 4.2 GHz. WMI incorrectly reported it at 4.0 GHz (the stock max clock speed).

I've also noticed System Properties doesn't usually report clock speed right. I assume it is also pulling its data using WMI. I also understand CPUs don't always run at highest clock speed. In my circumstance, it was running at highest clock speed (according to CPU-Z).

The reason I want to figure this out is to compare current clock speed, and max clock speed (to determine if a CPU is overclocked in my application).

Here's an example of my code.

```
Imports System.Management
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cpuSpeed As String = String.Empty
    Dim wmiObj As ManagementObjectSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")
    For Each element As ManagementObject In wmiObj.Get()
        cpuSpeed = element.GetPropertyValue("CurrentClockSpeed").ToString
    Next
    MsgBox("Your current CPU speed is " & cpuSpeed, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "WMI Test")
End Sub
End Class
```

The result is simply the stock clock speed. It won't tell me the current.

Comment: How does this relate to VB.NET ? is there any code you can share?

Comment: Well, I'd like a solution in VB.NET. I guess I didn't make it clear that I am using WMI in VB. I didn't think it was relevant, but sure.